# What is the tersest way for a speaker to request from the listener to refrain from making any inferences from a statement of fact?

Tags: word-choice

What is the tersest way for a speaker to request from the listener to refrain from making any inferences from a statement of fact?

Suppose as part of a narrative, I want to say something happened (e.g. "I stubbed my toe on the bench").

At the same time, I don't want the listener to jump to any conclusions based on that statement. For example, that: my toe is in pain, or I'm upset, or the bench was in a bad spot or had been moved.

How can I state a fact with this proviso efficiently?

Comment: "... but don't make any assumptions," is the first thing that comes to mind.

Comment: There really isn't any foolproof way. If you make a statement of fact, anyone who understands it can draw inferences from it; there's no way to prevent that. If you're careful to state only what happened -- without triggering any [presuppositions](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/presuptrig.pdf), which takes some attention to detail -- then you may do so without being responsible for any conclusions the listener draws. ***Provided*** you didn't lead them to those conclusions.

Comment: It's a little bit rude, but "let me finish before you speak" is essentially what you're saying, I think. And it's not polite. That's why they're **con**versations, not versations.

Comment: You stated it yourself: "Don't jump to any conclusions".

Comment: This is like asking someone not to think of pink elephants.

Comment: Since it's part of a narrative, a non-verbal gesture is the tersest way to make your point-  as you approach the part of your statement where an inference could start to be drawn, you hold up your fist with a raised index finger and simultaneously give the listener a stern look as if looking over the top of your glasses.  This will be taken to mean, "Now, don't go jumping to conclusions. Just listen."

Comment: @Robusto- I swear the first time I read your comment there were two more words there, but now there just seems to be a long blank space before the period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps *[take at face value](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+at+face+value)*

> to accept something because of the way it first looks or seems, without thinking about what else it could mean

*Cambridge Idioms Dictionary* (found at *idioms.thefreedictionary.com*)